# Should I create two similar tables or one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

In my database I have flights wich are formed by two air tickets in both sides. So, to create flight object I should create two tickets in both sides. The tickets have field in database "flight direction" with two values: 1)"there" 2)"from". I can't figure out how to make form where i can create two tickets with different sides at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a callback in your `Flight` model. This callback will be executed after the Flight is created (= initialized and saved to database).

```
class Flight
  has_many :tickets
  ...
  after_create :create_tickets

  def create_tickets
    tickets.create(flight_direction:  'from')
    tickets.create(flight_direction:  'there')
  end
end
```

This will automatically create two Ticket records in database that are associated with the Flight record.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I whant two create this two tickets from one form while I'm filling the data of tickets. Something like this:

class Ticket

  def new
    ticket_there = Ticket.new(flight_direction:  'there')
    ticket_back = Ticket.new(flight_direction:  'back')
  end
end